# Connecting Aptana with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, aptana, aptana3

I am new to Git and Aptana. I have downloaded Git from the location:windows.github.com. It installed fine.

I see a default integration of Aptana with Git, but what I dont know where it is pointing to which server location?

I want to host my code on GitHub so that I can keep different machine in Synch.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between Git and Github's application. Once you install both [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Github's Windows application](http://windows.github.com/) you need to setup both Git *and* [Github in your PC](https://help.github.com/) — detailed help available in their respective sites.

Both Github's app and Aptana use the settings from your Git profile in your PC while committing and these details are simply, your username and email (and other profile settings if any).

If you want to use Aptana to connect to Github, you can do so by using: `Wrench icon in the project sidebar > More > Add remote` Here you must add a remote repository which will be used by Aptana. [More details on Git remotes here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote). To avoid unnecessary hassles, the Windows Github app makes this management easier. Aptana provides a GUI around Git which is exactly what the Github App does, with some additional features and ease.

Hope I haven't confused you a little more.